# How can I convert current time to a float value?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a slider which can be used as a countdown timer, how can I set the value of `rangeCircularSlider.startPointValue` to my current time value, because this takes in as a float value. I'm writing this code:

```
    let date=Date()
    let calendar=Calendar.current
    let hour=calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
    let minute=calendar.component(.minute, from: date)

    let dayInSeconds = 24 * 60 * 60
    rangeCircularSlider.maximumValue = CGFloat(dayInSeconds)

    rangeCircularSlider.startPointValue = CGFloat(1 * 60)
    rangeCircularSlider.endPointValue = CGFloat(8 * 60)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the date to a TimeInterval type (which is a double) and use that as starting point, for example:

```
let startPointValue = CGFloat(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
```

Comment: it gives me some vague value.

Comment: it's a time interval since a reference point (you can also set a different starting point using timeIntervalSince(date: Date) ). If you use that as your starting point, then you can increment from that and, if you need, you can convert back to a date.

Answer (score 1):

The code gives the time elapsed since the start of third millennium.

```
 let now = Date()
 now.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
```

## Playground Output:

```
"Mar 27, 2017, 10:35 AM"
512283940.76486
```

Refer to this [link](http://www.globalnerdy.com/2015/01/26/how-to-work-with-dates-and-times-in-swift-part-one/)